# c# how to write "if contains substring"?

Tags: c#, substring

Can someone tell me how it should look?

```
   if (foundWord.value.Contains("przedaw".Substring(1, 7)))
    {
    for foundWord.value == "Sprzedawca" or "Sprzedawca:" or "Sprzedawca: " or "sprzedawca" etc...?
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please specify the question? What's the input and what is the desired output?

Comment: Rephrase the question please, It's not clear what do you need.

Comment: I have deserialized xml and i am looking for word like sprzedawca etc, and that if is creating my object for this word. I would like my function to find that string at any xml. Usually it is just "Sprzedawca" but i need condition for every other posibilities

Comment: first it was just If(foundWord.value == "Sprzedawca"), but now i need it for other posibilities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need substring here.

```
if (foundWord.value.Contains("przedaw"))
```

if you want to be case insensitive, you may use a `ToLower()`

```
if (foundWord.value.ToLower().Contains("przedaw"))
```